# Java: Calling a method of an instanced instance

Tags: java, methods, call, instance

Beginner here.

Main.java:

```
public int foo = 0;

public static void main(String[] args){
   Window f = new Window();
   // do some other stuff
}

public static void incrementFooEverySecond(){
 while(true){
   foo++;
   bar.repaint();    // <- Problem here!
   Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
}
```

Window.java:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
  public Window(){
    this.setSize(X, Y) //...
    Area bar = new Area();
}}
```

Area.java:

```
public class Area extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

method1(){
  super.paint(g);
  g.setColor(Color.RED);
  g.fillRect(foo, foo, B, D);
  this.repaint();
}}
```

It works well this way, except for the 1 marked line. Upon start, the `method1()` is executed (I have no idea why, but that's not an issue). But I need to call the `repaint()` or `method1()`in the only instance of `Area` from a function in Main and I can't figure out how. Thanks for your thoughts.

Note that that I copied and simplified only the most important chunks of code.

Comment: Is `method1()` the actual name? or is it called `Area()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer as to why `method1()` is called as there is insufficient code in your question to show why.

However, the line `bar.repaint();` is a problem because the variable `bar` is not in scope for this code. The only instance of `bar` that you show in your code is created inside the constructor of your `Window` class, and goes out of scope at the end of that method.

To solve this problem, you would need to add an instance variable `bar` to your Window class like this:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
    private Area bar;

    public Window(){
        this.setSize(X, Y) //...
        bar = new Area();   
    }
}
```

Then, you would need a method to expose the repaint functionality such as:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
    private Area bar;

    public Window(){
        this.setSize(X, Y) //...
        bar = new Area();   
    }

    public void repaintBar() {
        bar.repaint();
    }
}
```

Now in your `Main` class (same problem for `Window f` as for `Area bar` above):

```
public class Main {
    static Window f;
    public int foo = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        f = new Window();
        // do some other stuff
    }

    public static void incrementFooEverySecond(){
        while(true){
            foo++;
            f.repaintBar();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer, and Jason has gone to some trouble to explain the answer to the question you asked.  Be aware that, because you show incomplete code, you might do what he suggested and still have it fail.  I say this for two reasons: practically by definition you can't be sure what the "important chunks of code" really are, and you are attempting GUI programming (complex) before you understand variable scope (basic).  Good luck with it.  And if Jason did answer your question, mark it as an answer; if was helpful, also upvote it, that's the way SO works.